# How to compare two vectors (a numeric one and a boolean one)?

Tags: r, vector, boolean

So I have two vectors, one contains numeric values and the other contains boolean values, they have the same size and I'd like to keep only the numeric values that are aligned with the TRUE value.

```
[1] 17 18 19

#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

In the example above I'd like to keep the value "17" and "18"

Comment: Just do `v1[v2]` where `v1 <- 17:19; v2 <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)`

Comment: where `v1` is the numeric vector and `v2` is the boolean one